# How to force rerendering of RenderFragment in blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

## The problem

I am doing a Modal component in Blazor that edits records of a grid. I would like to render it with currently selected record if the user clicks on my button.

## What have I tried

I made a helper class called `ViewProvider` with a function `Edit(T current)` where `T` is a class representing my record. Edit function returns `RenderFragment`

I then placed `@ViewProvider.Edit(Current)` in my `Grid.razor` where I meant to show the modal window. It is called everytime grid changes it's state. However, the modal will popup exactly once and it won't rerender with fresh record after button is clicked. I suppose Blazor sees my modal internally in it's tree and thinks nothing changed, because the view is the same (although data in the view is different).

## Question

How do I force my Modal to show with current record everytime a button is clicked? Or how do I change a part of RenderFragment to update data in the view?

Edit:

Here's the code:

Grid.razor

```
@if (EditedCell.HasValue) {
    @ViewProvider.Edit(Current, "Edit")
}
```

ViewProvider.cs

```
public override RenderFragment Edit(T current, string modalName)
{
            RenderFragment editView = (builder) =>
            {
                foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
                {
                    builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
                    builder.AddAttribute(1, "class", "mt10 mb10");
                    builder.OpenElement(2, "label");
                    builder.AddContent(3, property.Name);
                    builder.CloseElement();
                    builder.OpenComponent<InputBox>(4);
                    builder.AddAttribute(5, "Type", InputBox.SetInputType(property.PropertyType));
                    builder.AddAttribute(6, "Value", property.GetValue(current).ToString());
                    builder.AddAttribute(7, "Class", "right");
                    builder.CloseComponent();
                    builder.CloseElement();
                }
                builder.OpenElement(8, "button");
                builder.AddAttribute(9, "class", "primary");
                builder.AddAttribute(10, "onclick", EventCallback.Factory.Create<MouseEventArgs>(this, s => { EditOnClick(current, s); }));
                builder.AddContent(11, "Zapisz");
                builder.CloseElement();
            };
            return AddModal(editView, modalName);
}

public RenderFragment AddModal(RenderFragment ChildContent, string modalName)
{
            RenderFragment modalFragment = (builder) =>
            {
                builder.OpenComponent<Modal>(0);
                builder.AddAttribute(1, "Name", modalName);
                builder.AddAttribute(2, "ChildContent", ChildContent);
                builder.CloseComponent();
            };
            return modalFragment;
}
```

Comment: There are ways to achieve Two-Way Data Binding in Blazor. Could you please provide some code?

Comment: https://blazor-university.com/components/two-way-binding/

Comment: @panoskarajohn eddited my answer to add code